# Map String to its data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following type:

```
data Color = Red
           | Yellow
           | Green
           | ...
```

I want a function mapping string representation to specific Color.

```
str2Color :: String -> Color

str2Color "Red": Red
str2Color "Yellow": Yellow
str2Color "Green": Green
```

I could enumerate all strings, but problem is the list of all colors is very long. Is there any simpler way?

ps: Let's assume all input strings have a corresponding Color, for ease of exposition.

Comment: You can make a `deriving Read` from the `Color` type, then you can use `read :: String -> Color` to convert a string to the corresponding `Color`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @WillemVanOnsem noted in a comment, you can have the compiler derive a `Read` instance for your `Color` type:

```
data Color = Red | Yellow | Blue
  deriving (Read, Show)
```

which then makes available the function:

```
read :: String -> Color
```

to convert a `String` to the corresponding `Color`.

Full example:

```
data Color = Red | Yellow | Blue
  deriving (Read, Show)

main = do
  print (read "Red" :: Color)
  print (read "Blue" :: Color)
```

`read` throws an exception if the `String` isn’t a valid `Color`. To handle this case yourself, you can use `Text.Read.readMaybe :: (Read a) => String -> Maybe a` and pattern-match on the result.

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

main = do
  print (readMaybe "Red" :: Maybe Color)    -- Just Red
  print (readMaybe "Beans" :: Maybe Color)  -- Nothing
  s <- getLine
  case readMaybe s of
    Just color -> print (color :: Color)
    Nothing -> putStrLn ("Invalid color: '" ++ s ++ "'")
```